# Java encryption to javascript decryption AES, CryptoJS, CTR

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I am having encryption and decryption code already in place.
But now i am just going to use java encryption for encrypting the text.
And going to decrypt it in JavaScript using CryptoJS.

```
@Service
public class EncryptionServiceImpl extends EncryptionService {

    protected static final int BLOCK_SIZE_BYTES = 16;

    protected static final int BLOCK_SIZE_BITS = 128;

    protected SecureRandom secureRandom;

    protected int keySizeByte;

    @Value("${encryption.key}")
    private String keyString ;


    public EncryptionServiceImpl() {
        byte[] key = keyString.getBytes();
        //create secret key spec instance
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        try {
            cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        }
        //create secure random number generator instance
        secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    }


    public String encrypt(String data) {
        byte[] dataByte = new byte[0];
        try {
            dataByte = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        }
        //create iv
        SecureRandom randomSecureRandom;
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = null;
        byte[] iv = new byte[0];
        try {
            randomSecureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
            randomSecureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
            ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
        try {
            cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParams);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        //return concatenation of iv + encrypted data
        byte[] encByteArr;
        try {
            encByteArr = ArrayUtils.addAll(iv, cipher.doFinal(dataByte));
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return  Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(encByteArr);
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedData) {
         byte[] decodedValue = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedData);
        byte[] iv = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE_BYTES];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, iv, 0, BLOCK_SIZE_BYTES);
        try {
            cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        }

        //return decrypted value
        byte[] decryptedByteArray;
        try {
            decryptedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(data, BLOCK_SIZE_BYTES, data.length - BLOCK_SIZE_BYTES);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        }
        try {
            return new String(decryptedByteArray,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }
        return new String(decryptedByteArray);
    }
}
```

I want to do the exact decryption in JS that what i did in java.
I am new to JS. 
i am trying below things to convert it in js.
I think looking at the code, i need to get rid of IV from encrypted text. but IV generated with SecureRandom. Unable to figure out how to get the rid of IV in JS.

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */
function decryption(val) {
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(val);
    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("<my encryption key used in java code>");
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(val);
    const valueDec = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        { ciphertext: encrypted },
        key,
        { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CTR, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, iv: iv, }));
    return valueDec;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any base 64 decoding of the key in Java. And your IV in JavaScript seems to be separate from the ciphertext while it is part of the ciphertext in Java. If you cannot get those kind of things right you can try forever.

Comment: Note that the exception handling in Java is really sub-par. If you don't know how to handle, then revert to a runtime exception. In that case you don't have to use the spurious and dangerous `new byte[0]` calls as the assignment is done within the `try ... catch`.